# Translated app pages: do I need to duplicate for each region speaking the same language?

Tags: android, google-play

This question is about the app page on Google Play. The platform allows the publisher to provide translations for the app page. Each different version corresponds to a language associated with a specific region, for example en-US, es-ES, de-DE etc. 
At the moment there is no way to simply provide a version for a language (whatever the region), it must be for a language corresponding to a specific region.

Does anybody know what happens in the following scenario:

- a canadian user who lives in Quebec with a device set to language fr-CA visits an app page on Google Play
- the publisher of this app has provided 2 sets of language: en-US (default) and fr-FR.
- the publisher has NOT provided a translation for fr-CA

Will the user be shown the default version of the app page (en-US), or will he be shown the fr-FR version since his device language is FR?

Comment: I am highly interested too.

Comment: I have the same question, my App base language is EN (en-US), but I have Spanish and adding Portuguese translation now, so I'm thinking about pt-PT and pt-BR. Since my Spanish App page is es-ES, I have checked it with es-US user settings and it shows App page in Spanish. So I hope the fallback language for all Spanish locales will be "es" anyway (in opposite to google help, that states a fallback language is en-US for non-translated pages). So translation will be required only if you have a diffference there.